# How to represent byte json string in Python

Tags: python, json, string, byte, kazoo

I am working with Python and Zookeeper as I am using kazoo library in Python. This question is not about Zookeeper or kazoo library. I guess this is mainly related to Python.

Below are my two variables -

```
new_error_str = "Error occurred on machine %s in datacenter %s on the %s of process %s" % (host_info, local_dc, step, process_name)
new_error_key = "error_%s" % (timestamp_in_ms)
```

And now I need to use these two variables to make a byte json string and then write the that json string as the data in the Zookeeper node so below is the syntax by which we create a node and write the data as well -

```
zk.create(date_znode_path, b'{"'+new_error_key+'":"' + new_error_str + '"}', None, True)
```

Somehow the above line throws an exception as -

```
TypeError: value must be a byte string
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing here? I am trying to make a JSON String of above variables.

Here is details about [kazoo library](https://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_usage.html#zookeeper-crud)

**UPDATE:-**

If I use this syntax, then it works fine -

```
b'{"hostname":"' + get_hostname() + '"}', None, True)
```

I can see data like this -

```
{"hostname":"machineA"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use json module:

```
import json
zk.create(date_znode_path, json.dumps({new_error_key : new_error_str}, ensure_ascii=True), None, True)
```

Manually constructing json is tricky, what if input contains quotes? It is always better to use tools that can escape everything and are well tested against all edge cases.

Comment: The `bytes` constructor raises an error for me if I pass it a string. You can pass it a second `encoding` argument, but using `str.encode` may be clearer.

Comment: I am running Python version 2.7.3 and just updated the question with an example

Comment: I adjusted my answer. Constructing manually json is tricky when encodings come to play, it is best to just delegate to tools that were made for this, right? ;)

Comment: What is the purpose of using `ensure_ascii=True` here?

Comment: @SSH even more conservative than byte, escapes everything outside 128 range. Probably overkill, but won't hurt for sure.

Comment: sure.. One last question, after storing this string like this. I will be extracting this string back by using UTF-8 format so this should fine right? meaning whatever I am storing it like this, it should come fine when I will read it back using UTF-8 format?

Comment: well... I would keep keys in ascii range, but that's like no-brainer for errors, isn't it? Everything else depends on how rest of framework is written, it _should_ work. For sure it won't hard to write a few test cases, but again - it is a no brainer, everything involving different encodings should be covered with tests.